# Arduino (ATmega328) in-circuit programming

Tags: arduino, atmega, isp

I am designing a circuit/software for some guy...

I am using an ATmega328 surface-mounted microcontroller in the design and am just supplying the schematic and code. He is going to build it (make a PCB) and use it for his business.

I was going to program it using the Arduino IDE since I have more experience with that and was going to add in an ISP header and suggest using this http://docs-europe.electrocomponents.com/webdocs/0dba/0900766b80dba9b4.pdf to program it..

However I noticed that the 328 is not listed under the supported devices for that programmer?? And even if it was I am unsure if that would work using the regular Arduino program?

What is the best way for me to do this? I need to be able to test the code on my Arduino Uno, and also provide the means for him to easily program the code onto a new chip on the PCB.

I don't mind programming it outside of the Arduino IDE if I need to as long as I can test that code with my Arduino Uno.

I tried looking around for answers, but I didn't find anything satisfactory. Here is the schematic I have so far, with an ISP header (that apparently isn't supported?)

[image]

Comment: http://www.atmel.com/images/atmel-2521-avr-hardware-design-considerations_application-note_avr042.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> See AVR Studio 4 online help ...

...

> **Created:** Tue 01 Nov 2005 08:17:09 AM EST

The '328 didn't exist until *2009*. This is why you go to the [primary source](http://www.atmel.com/webdoc/avrispmkii/index.html) when possible.

But yes, that programmer supports the '328, as well as *all* AVR chips that support ISP. The software needs to support the programmer and the chip as well, but I can tell you that [AVRDUDE](http://www.nongnu.org/avrdude/), which is the AVR command line programmer of choice (as well as the one that the Arduino IDE uses), does. You're covered.

Comment: Here's a list of supported devices: http://www.atmel.com/webdoc/atmelstudio/supported.devices.AVR.Mega.html

Comment: That's the list for Atmel (*not* just "AVR" anymore) Studio. The AVRDUDE list is [here](http://www.nongnu.org/avrdude/user-manual/avrdude_4.html).